# What is the document that Horikita Manabu saw in episode 4?

Tags: japanese-language, classroom-of-the-elite

I was watching *Classroom of the Elite* on Muse Asia YouTube channel where I encountered this scene in episode 04 time ~08:22. After seeing this document, president Horikita Manabu started laughing. There's no subtitle nor translator's note about this document.

[image]

What is the content of this document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document is a report about the complaint by Class 1-C that was explained in the scene following this.

[image]

<sup>Rotated and brigthened the shadowed part</sup>

> President of the Student Council　Manabu Horikita
> .　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Reporter　Student Council secretary
> .　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Akane Tachibana
>
> .　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　**Report**
>
> Time of occurrence　June 30　around 18:00
>
> Persons involved　Class 1-C　Daichi Ishizaki　　　Class 1-D　Ken Sudou
> .　　　　　　　 　Class 1-C　Kyougo Komiya
> .　　　　　　　　 Class 1-C　Reo Kondou
>
> **Incident Summary**
>
> The incident ​occurred on June 30 around 18:00, located on the 3rd floor of a particular building [...]
>
> Ishizaki, Komiya, and Kondou of Class 1-C students [...]
> took an assault from Sudou of Class 1-D students [...]
>
> [this part afterward is unreadable due to low contrast]